# Is it illegal to sell my original Video game music for a fan game?

Tags: business, music

So I am making an original video game soundtrack for a fan game I have started developing. The thing is that I want to sell this soundtrack on BandCamp, and IDK if it's legal sense I am going to be using it in a fan game. I have looked this up and I found no results for this subject. I don't plan on selling the game, just the soundtrack I made for it. So is it illegal if I do so?

Answer (score 1):

I can see no reason why it would not be legal.  If you create a work of art you can do what you like with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with the terms of service for BandCamp, but as long as you retain the ownership of the music and there is no stipulation preventing alternate means of distribution, then you should be fine to use it as a soundtrack in your game and sell it.